# Preloader animation with image clipping

Tags: javascript, css, animation, clipping

I'm trying to recreate [this](https://senorsanchez.be) animation effect, so the whole sequence of the blue part sliding in from the right covering the white background, the image clipping animation and then the user interface animations. Any advice on how to approach this? Thanks! p.s. [video presentation](https://youtu.be/JPg809sQQr4) of what im trying to make.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: hi @AlokSingh thanks for commenting! I figured ithas nothing to do with image clipping really, it's actually few stacked up layers with different z-indexes with animations that are chained together using anime.js and greensock libraries. What confused me was bunch of SVG code in that website, that actually represented the paths of how to draw a "signature logo" of the website. thanks again!